# QWidget::heightForWidth How set set the ratio between hight and width if no Layout is used

Tags: qt, user-interface, qwidget

The ratio of a ´`QWidget` sub class is width = height. How I can set this, so the widget can not set to this values: `QWidgetSub::resize(10, 4);`? And so this statement is true `QWidgetSub::heightForWidth(10) == 10`?

Comment: rephrase your question, it not clear what is your problem.

Comment: The target is to set something like a resize policy. So the user can not resize the window to a bad ratio. If the width is 10 then the hight must be 10 too. If the width is 20 then the height is 20. Is my problem no clear?